# Hide the Country option in cart page

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, shipping

in cart page, you can see there is an option to find shipping charges by entering the zip code.

we removed "State" field, so its displaying like this now :

[image]

you can see **country * "India"**.

I want to hide this. i done this by commented the related code in

```
 app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
<!--
    <label for="country"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Country') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
    <?php echo Mage::getBlockSingleton('directory/data')->getCountryHtmlSelect($this->getEstimateCountryId()) ?>
    </div>
-->
```

now , its not calculating shipping charges when i entered zip code.

what is the correct procedure to hide & why shipping charges are not calculating when i hide the "country".

also its not displaying the message "Shipping is available or not"

ex: you can check here in cart page by adding this item to cart  [link](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/chhota-bheem-jaggu-keychain.html)

[image]

Comment: can you provide live link?

Comment: [link](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/chhota-bheem-jaggu-keychain.html) pls check here in cart page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't comment hide by adding the div. this will work for you..

```
<div style="display:none"><label for="country"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Country') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
    <?php echo Mage::getBlockSingleton('directory/data')->getCountryHtmlSelect($this->getEstimateCountryId()) ?>
    </div></div>
```

Comment: how to do the same in magento 2

Comment: @sangan most probably do it with js. i didn't do anything on M2 checkout yet.

Comment: ok,i tried but no effect